# df.loc with more than one condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to produce a variable in my dataframe that states if the specfied time is in rush hour using two other variables 'hour' and 'weekday?'.When I run the code it only states 'NaN', can someone guide me on what is wrong with my code? The code that i am using can be seen below:

````
df.loc[(df['hour'] <7) & (df['hour']>10) & (df['hour'] <3) & (df['hour']>6) , 'Rush_hour?'] = 'No' 
df.loc[(df['hour'] >=3) & (df['hour']<=6) & (df['weekday?'] == 'yes'), 'Rush_hour?'] = ' Yes-pm'  ```
````

Comment: you can use the query() method if you are using a newer version of pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: when i use df.query i get the error "'method' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: `(df['hour'] <7) & (df['hour']>10)` 
I don't know any number that can be greater than 10 and less than 7

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct and the code works. The problem is as [ansev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11884237/ansev) stated, your condition never yields True and therefore the only values you see are NaN.